How to login to Azure with MFA user in deployment scripts?
I have an Entra user that runs most deployment scripts in jenkins and the initial login to gain access to the Azure subscriptions and resources is as follows:
  az login -u <USER_NAME> -p <PWD>
  az account set --subscription <MY_SUBSCRIPTION>

and then I have access to the resources and can continue with the script.
Now if the user is MFA enabled then this wont work as they need to enter a code.
Is there any other way i can do the similar using az cli with an mfa user ?

Does this script have to be run as a scheduled job? If it is to be run interactively you could use az login without sending a password. This will open a web-browser for you to authenticate normally (with MFA).

According to the MSDoc, it is clearly given that:

If multi-factor authentication is enabled for your credentials, you must log in using the interactive option or use service principal authentication.

So, it is not exactly possible to use non interactive authentication when the user is MFA enabled. In order to login automatically, you can use service principal authentication or login using the managed identity.
Refer Microsoft Q&A for the relevant information.
Create an entra service principal using CLI command az ad sp create and execute service principal login as shown in the below format.
$appid="xxxx"
$tenant="xxx"
az login --service-principal -u $appid -p=-7_8xxxxR-TaSj --tenant $tenant


Alternatively, non-interactive authentication can be done using the managed identity as shown below.
az login --identity


